# Using Json NewField without key value

Tags: javascript, json

```
{
    "ogrenci": [{
            "ogrenci_no": "2241",
            "ogrenci_ad": "Ahmet Çakıcı",
            "ogrenci_fakulte": "Teknik MYO"
        },
        {
            "ogrenci_no": "3899",
            "ogrenci_ad": "Mehmet Bayan",
            "ogrenci_fakulte": "Mühendislik"
        }
    ]
    "kampusler": []
}
```

This is my okul.json file

```
var x = require("./okul.json");

console.log(x);
x.ogrenci.NewField = {
    "ogrenci_no": "9999",
    "ogrenci_ad": "Ziya Öz",
    "ogrenci_fakulte": "Dil Bilimleri"
}
console.log("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n")
console.log(x);
```

This is my server.js.I'm trying to do append operation here.

As i said im trying to append a json object with using NewField and this both codes output is that :

```
{ ogrenci:
   [ { ogrenci_no: '2241',
       ogrenci_ad: 'Ahmet Çakıcı',
       ogrenci_fakulte: 'Teknik MYO' },
     { ogrenci_no: '3899',
       ogrenci_ad: 'Mehmet Bayan',
       ogrenci_fakulte: 'Mühendislik' },
     NewField: { ogrenci_no: '9999',
       ogrenci_ad: 'Ziya Öz',
       ogrenci_fakulte: 'Dil Bilimleri' } ],
  personel:
   [ { personel_no: '33',
       personel_ad: 'Orhan Akbağ',
       personel_statu: 'Yemekhane Görevlisi' },
     { personel_no: '59',
       personel_ad: 'Murat Erdoğan',
       personel_statu: 'Öğretim Görevlisi' } ],
  kampusler: [] }

Actually I appended it successfully but as you see there is writing NewField : {..} 
I don't wan to add my JSON item with a header, key value.
How can I avoid this?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use:

```
x.ogrenci.push({
    "ogrenci_no": "9999",
    "ogrenci_ad": "Ziya Öz",
    "ogrenci_fakulte": "Dil Bilimleri"
})
```